# Geocoding Gmaps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-markers

Im buildng a webapp on Rails with Google maps API (still in developement, so I dont think the key is the issue), which works on Index view, but not in Show.
This is what i´ve done so far:

```html
gem "geocoder"

create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string "time"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "status"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "car_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.index ["car_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_car_id"
  end
  
 <!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
 
<body>
  <!-- [...] -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" %>
</body>



 <!-- Appointments controller -->
 
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @appointments = Appointment.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude: nil)
    @markers = @appointments.map do |a|
      {
        lat: a.latitude,
        lng: a.longitude
      }
    end
  end
  
    def show
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @markers =
      {
        lat: @appointment.latitude,
        lng: @appointment.longitude
      }
  end
  
  <!-- Index and show view -->
  
    <div
  id="map"
  style="width: 50%;
  height: 600px;"
  data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
></div>


 <!-- map.js -->
 
 
// app/javascript/packs/map.js
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) { // don't try to build a map if there's no div#map to inject in
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  map.addMarkers(markers);
  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }
}
 
  <!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<!-- [ ... ] -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag "map" %>
```

It works perfectly on index, but not on show. I know `@markers` works as i can access `lat:` and `lng:` correcty from the view, but the marker is non existent and the map shows the middle of the pacific ocean. What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The index `@markers` is an array and the show `@markers` is merely a hash, which I assume would be the culprit.

Comment: Yeap... That was it hehe, thanks Josh Brody!

Comment: yw. you should consider making the coordinates hash a method on your model :)

Comment: Just injecting the hash into an array fixed the issue :)